# Converting Times in Excel with minutes and seconds

Tags: excel, time

In Excel, I need to be able to extract a time of `51:25:00` that is entered as `[h]:mm:ss` and convert it into minutes and seconds as `51:25` and have the output show `51:25` as in `51 minutes` and `25 seconds.` Once I have extracted that time I need to convert it all into minutes so into `51.467 minutes` that way I can perform other calculations with those minutes.

I cannot figure out a way to use `LEFT()` or `MID()` because of the format of the orginal cells.

I can enter in values as `51:25` with the format: `[mm]:ss` but that is quite time consuming. But I also do not know how to extract that time into minutes.

I am looking for a formula that can convert the `[h]:mm:ss` into the required `[mm]:ss` and then another formula to look at the minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
=MINUTE(A1/60)+SECOND(A1/60)/60
```

[image]

More robustly perhaps,

```
=HOUR(A1/60)*60+MINUTE(A1/60)+SECOND(A1/60)/60
```

[image]

Comment: I do not even need to convert into the minute and second thing. Brilliant.

Comment: Yeah, division by 60 gives you `[mm]:ss`, if you needed that as an intermediate step...

Comment: Sadly sometimes we are only good as the data provided to us in that format. But this works for now given how the data is given to me.

Comment: Note that this won't work with data like `81:25:00`. Not sure if that's an issue.

Comment: Noting over 60 in that hour column works. Hmmmm. It will be a problem, but at least I have an idea now. Thank you.

Comment: You could modify to `=HOUR(A1/60)*60+MINUTE(A1/60)+SECOND(A1/60)/60`.