# Time passed since x convert seconds using forumulas and/or vba

Tags: excel

I have to log hours in a CRM and the only way to get a running total of the already logged hours is displayed in seconds.  In trying to get excel to consider the current time (offset by 08:30 AM) minus the amount of seconds entered, for example;

When the current time is 10:43 AM and I've entered 3600 into a cell the output should be (10:43 - 08:30) - ((3600 / 60) /60) = 1.22 or 01:43.

I can't seem to find anything online in a similar situation and all the formals I've tried end up with failed results, thanks in advance for taking the time to check out my post, cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Times in Excel with minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776967/converting-times-in-excel-with-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: I disagree with your assessment Calestini, I'm not asking for assistance regarding how to format it, I'm asking for;

Take the current time
Consider a static start time
Reduce the value by the amount of seconds entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide the seconds by 3600 to get hours then by 24 to get fractions of a day:

```
=MOD(A1,1)-B1-C1/3600/24
```

where A1 contains NOW(), B1 contains the base time (I have used 7:30) and C1 contains the number of seconds.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, I'm going to research MOD now as this was the missing part to me figuring it out myself, thank you so much Tom!!!